# MySQL query to find a slightly complex relationship

Tags: mysql

I am trying to devise a MySQL query to select a specific record based off 2 parameters. Lets say I have 3 tables. Users, Conversations, and UserConvo where UserConvo is a reference table that links the Many-to-Many relationship between a User and any Conversation that they are having. Think of it as a very basic web chat.

Now, if given an arbitrary number of UserIds (i.e. [1,2,3]), I want to find a Conversation that involves EXACTLY these Users. Therefore, for the case of UserIds 1, 2, and 3, I want to see if there exists a Conversation where only user 1, 2, and 3 are included.

Is there a purely MySQL way to do this? My first thoughts are to just query the Conversations in which UserId 1, 2 and 3 are present. Then, somehow check each record to see if all ConversationIds match, but I do not have a whole lot of MySQL experience and am not sure of its potential.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.  It uses `count` with `case` - the idea is to compare the overall count per conversation to those where the user id in (1,2,3):

```
select c.id
from conversations c
  join userconversations uc on c.id = uc.conversationid
  join users u on uc.userid  = u.id
group by c.id
having count(u.id) = count(case when u.id in (1,2,3) then 1 end)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42fdf/5)

Comment: The case you gave appears to work and let me know if I'm wrong, but if I change `case when u.id in (1,2,3)` to be `(1,2,3,4)`, then shouldn't I get just conversation Id 1 instead of 2? However, if I do that I get both 1 and 2.

Comment: Your solution does seem to work correctly, but would you mind explaining that part after the `HAVING` clause? It is not clear why that works the way it does and I would love to know why

Comment: @MattHintzke -- no worries.  When using count with case, it only counts the number of records that match the criteria, in this case, user id in 1,2,3.  That number has to match the overall count of returned results.  That's the first having clause.  That number also has to match the number of returned results you're looking for (i.e. the number of users).  That's the second one.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, I think that makes sense. It just threw me off because it seems weird to be comparing 2 values with `COUNT(*)` at the same time.  Thank you tho!